# Cannot connect to MongoDB outside the docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I've got the following docker compose file with MongoDB container:

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - ./keyfile.txt:/data/keyfile.txt
    entrypoint:
      - bash
      - -c
      - |
        cp /data/keyfile.txt /data/replica.key
        chmod 400 /data/replica.key
        chown 999:999 /data/replica.key
        exec docker-entrypoint.sh $$@
    command: "--bind_ip_all --replSet rs0 --keyFile /data/replica.key"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    healthcheck:
      test: test $$(echo "rs.initiate().ok || rs.status().ok" | mongo -u root -p example --quiet) -eq 1
      interval: 10s
      retries: 3
    network_mode: host
```

I have to get rid of `network_mode: host`, so I changed it to

```
ports:
  - "27017:27017"
```

After that change, I'm not able to connect to the mongo outside of the docker network.
I'm trying to connect to the database using Compass with the following URI:
`mongodb://root:example@localhost:27017/?authMechanism=DEFAULT`

How to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

This is fully working example.

I'm recommending to create custom DB and custom user instead of using root user.

Use special path of auto-executing queries and create one or multiple databases.

```
    mongodb:
        image: mongo:latest
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "27017:27017"
        volumes:
            - ./var/mongodb:/data/db
            - ./mongo-init.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:ro
        environment:
            MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
            MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass
```

## mongo-init.js

```
db = db.getSiblingDB('SOME_DB');
db.createUser({
    user: 'some_db_user',
    pwd:  '12345',
    roles: [{ role: 'readWrite', db: 'SOME_DB' }],
});

db = db.getSiblingDB('SOME_OTHER_DB');
db.createUser({
    user: 'some_other_db_user',
    pwd:  '12345',
    roles: [{ role: 'readWrite', db: 'SOME_OTHER_DB' }],
});
db.createCollection('test');
```